# Vitamio Media Player Licensing

Tags: android, licensing, media-player

I've managed to get integrate [Vitamio](http://vitamio.org/) into a project. However I'm not clear on the licensing requirements for this library. I can find no information on their website (which is currently down) or in their source code. Although some of the files seem to have Apache 2.0 licenses.

It seems that it might be based on [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/legal.html), which looks to have LGPLV2.0 licensing requirements, but this isn't really clear.

I know that a few have recommended it here, so I imagine they might have also looked at licensing requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Vitamio 3.0 free to use for any developers now. 
Vitamio 4.0 License visit http://www.vitamio.org/en/License/

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Vitamio in our project. Normally Vitamio is a library project. you need to include that libary project in your project and import that vitamio player in ur Activity class dont need to get licence.

Comment: Are you sure ? since how many times you are using it in your project ?